# What is the difference between $ and Ember.$?

Tags: jquery, ember.js

Recently I have been observing ember devs using `Ember.$` over `$` for jquery. What is the main difference and why should i prefer `Ember.$` ?

Comment: [Many JavaScript libraries use $ as a function or variable name, just as jQuery does. In jQuery's case, $ is just an alias for jQuery, so all functionality is available without using $.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) In other words, it would seem to be to avoid conflicts with other javascript libraries.

Comment: thats the only reason?..coz i can still access $ even thgh Ember.$ is available..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't develop with Ember.js. However, this is fairly common practice.

As a rule of thumb, it's best to have as few global variables as possible. This reduces the possibility for conflict. It wouldn't be unreasonable for a developer to assign a different value to `$` if they wanted to. For instance, a developer might use the Prototype library, which also uses the `$` symbol.

<sub>(This would be pretty silly behaviour most of the time, but it *might* be necessary.)</sub>

Using `Ember.$`, however, pretty much guarantees access to jQuery. It *could* be overwritten, but it almost certainly won't be.

Comment: yea..i think this may be the reason...i tried to set $ to empty object... If there is no Ember.$ all ember views fails..so i guess they created for same..

Answer (score 6):

Both $ and Ember.$ points to same jQuery function. The only difference is that $ is a global javascript valiable and can be easily overwritten by other javascript frameworks. So it's a good practice to use Ember.$ in your ember applications.

Answer (score 0):

Ember.$ is an alias to the jQuery object: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.12.0/packages/ember-views/lib/main.js#L534

btw if you want to use $.getJSON or $.ajax I would recommend https://github.com/instructure/ic-ajax11 which is an wrapper around the jQuery functions that works with the Ember run loop3